# What really means "Missing artifact..." on Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, artifact

I created a **Maven** project with **Eclipse**, and when I try to add dependencies using the add button, for example **spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar**, I get this error:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE
```

I looked into my **.m2** directory and, in fact, there isn't any file called spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar.

On the other hand, If I try to add the dependency **spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar** I don't get any error, since inside .m2 folder there is a file called spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar.

So, my question is: if maven doesn't find a dependency on my .m2 folder, shouldn't it download that dependency and save inside the .m2 folder??
Why Maven tells me "Missing artifact..." but doesn't download it?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe there isn't a public repository set up?

Comment: Hi @Veselin Davidov , what means public repository?

Comment: It downloads the required artifacts from somewhere right? It's usually a public maven repository that you have setup and that you trust (because it can give you different jar with the same name right? ). Usually maven has some predefined but still it might be disabled at your machine. Check the settings.xml in /m2 folder

Comment: What does the dependency look like in your pom.xml?

Comment: Thanks everybody. For every dependencies that caused problem, I deleted the relative folder inside .m2, I refreshed my project and I saw that those dependencies were, now, correctly downloaded. Maybe the problem was that Maven found already a folder called, for example spring-test-5.0.8, and didn't try to download the relative files, even though some files were missing in that folder. Do you think this may be the real problem?